# grails tab autocompletion not working within interactive mode

Tags: grails, sdkman

when I am within grails interactive mode the tab auto completion is not working. I have tried grails 2.5.3, 3.1.0 and 3.1.1 and none of them are working.

Grails still works fine when I type in the full syntax.

My environment
- All my grails version were installed through SDKMAN
- Mac OS : El Capitan
- bash version: version 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: have anyone encounter this issues before? is it an issue on my bash terminal configuration?

Comment: i still couldn't find out why my grails tab autocompletion is not working in my environment.